# Spring MVC accessing Spring Security ConfigAttributes?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-boot

I want to produce HTTP Response Body with an error message referencing something like _"missing ... 'CUSTOM_AUTHORITY'"_ in addition to a `403 Forbidden` HTTP Status code.

My application is Spring Boot with a Spring-Security-Secured `@PreAuthorize` method within a Spring-MVC-REST `@Controller`:

### MyController

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/foo")
public FooController{
  @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('CUSTOM_AUTHORITY')")
  public Object getSomething(){ ... }
}
```

### GlobalExceptionHandlerResolver

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {
  @ExceptionHandler(AccessDeniedException.class)
  @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN)
  public Object forbidden(AccessDeniedException exception){ ... }
}
```

What I *want* is to expose/inject `Collection<ConfigAttribute>`. The [Spring Security docs reference it](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#authz-access-decision-manager).

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be a straightforward way of accomplishing this. The `AccessDecisionManager` (which is `AffirmativeBased`) throws the `AccessDeniedException` with none of the information you want. So if you want to "expose/inject" the `Collection<ConfigAttribute>`, you'll want to provide your own `AccessDecisionManager` that throws a custom exception that holds the `ConfigAttribute`s.

The easiest way to do this could be to wrap the default `AccessDecisionManager` with your own and delegate method calls to it:

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled=true)
CustomMethodSecurityConfig extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration

    @Override
    protected AccessDecisionManager accessDecisionManager() {
        AccessDecisionManager default = super.accessDecisionManager();
        MyCustomDecisionManager custom = new CustomDecisionManager(default);
    }
}
```

You could define your custom `AccessDecisionManager` as follows:

```
public class MyCustomDecisionManager implements AccessDecisionManager {

    private AccessDecisionManager default;

    public MyCustomDecisionManager(AccessDecisionManager acm) {
        this.default = acm;
    }

    @Override
    public void decide(Authentication authentication, Object object, Collection<ConfigAttribute> configAttributes) throws AccessDeniedException, InsufficientAuthenticationException{
        try {
            default.decide(authentication, object, configAttributes)
        } catch(AccessDeniedException ex) {
            throw new CustomAccessDeniedException(ex.getMessage(), configAttributes);
        }
    }

    // other methods delegate to default
}
```

Now whenever access is denied, you will get an exception that holds the `Collection<ConfigAttribute>`.

Your custom exception could look like this:

```
public class CustomAccessDeniedException extends AccessDeniedException {
    private Collection<ConfigAttribute> attributes;

    public CustomAccessDeniedException(String message, Collection<ConfigAttribute> attr) {
        super(message);
        this.attributes = attr;
    }

    public Collection<ConfigAttribute> getAttributes() {
        return this.attributes;
    }
}
```

Now your @ExceptionHandler could handle your `CustomAccessDeniedException` and have access to the `ConfigAttribute`s.

**HOWEVER...** 
I am not sure that will provide you with the error message you wanted. The `ConfigAttribute` interface only has one method:

```
String getAttribute();
```

And the javadoc states:

> If the ConfigAttribute cannot be expressed with sufficient precision as a String, null should be returned.

Since we can't rely on the interface method, how you deal with each `ConfigAttribute` will be heavily dependent on the type of the particular object you're dealing with.

For example, the `ConfigAttribute` that corresponds to `@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('CUSTOM_AUTHORITY')")` is `PreInvocationExpressionAttribute`, and to print something that resembles what you want, you could do:

```
PreInvocationExpressionAttribute attr = (PreInvocationExpressionAttribute)configAttribute;

String expressionString = attr.getAuthorizeExpression().getExpressionString();

System.out.println(expressionString); // "hasAuthority('CUSTOM_AUTHORITY')"
```

That's the major drawback. Also, you would get ***ALL*** the `ConfigAttribute`s, not necessarily the ones that failed.